# Improving an SQL query to get sensor events for a particular date & device type

Tags: mysql

We have an **event** mysql table where we store the events generated from different kind of sensors. Below is the create table query for the same table.

```
  CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `device_id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `device_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_event_device_idx` (`device_id`),
  KEY `event_device_type` (`device_type`),
  KEY `event_created_at_idx` (`created_at`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_event_device` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `device` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

We have a foreign key of *device_id* from **device** table and device table has a foreign key of *zone_id* from **zone** table.

We want to fetch the events of a particular *zone* and *device_type(e.g.THL sensor)* for a date(e.g. 2017-02-26). Below is the query I am running to do the same.

```
select e.data from event e 
left join device d on d.id = e.device_id 
where d.type = 'mdc' and d.zone_id = 'e451b2a1-5f6c-4a75-8038-30854926a9c0' and DATE(e.created_at) = '2018-03-01';
```

The explain plan gives below result for the same.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys                        | key                 | key_len | ref          | rows | filtered | Extra                              |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE,fk_device_zone_idx | fk_device_zone_idx  | 110     | const        |   23 |    10.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | NULL       | ref  | fk_event_device_idx                  | fk_event_device_idx | 110     | senzopt.d.id |  197 |   100.00 | Using where                        |
    +----+-------------+-------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+--------------+------+----------+------------------------------------+
```

The total number of records in event table is around 5 million and the above query takes approximately 1 second to execute and provide the result. I am looking to improve the sql execution time. Need suggestions for the same. Please let me know what all I could have done right.

***NOTE: I know I should move to NOSQL(Kafka/Cassandra/Spark) for the same. For that also, we are working in parallel. But, I am looking to improve the query to serve my clients better in current context.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query repeated in a slightly more readable format:

```
SELECT
    e.data
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN device d
    ON d.id = e.device_id 
WHERE
    d.type = 'mdc' AND
    d.zone_id = 'e451b2a1-5f6c-4a75-8038-30854926a9c0' AND
    DATE(e.created_at) = '2018-03-01';
```

We can improve the performance of this query by adding appropriate indices, and also be rephrasing it.

First, you can create a composite index in the `device` table on `(type, zone_id)`.  This should help with the `WHERE` clause.  Note that assuming `device.id` is the primary key of that table, it should already be indexed, meaning that the `LEFT JOIN` condition you have should be optimal.

You can also create an index on `event.created_at` column in the `event` table.  But in order to take advantage of it, we have to rewrite the non SARGable condition `WHERE DATE(e.created_at) = '2018-03-01'`:

```
WHERE e.created_at >= '2018-03-01' AND e.created_at < '2018-03-02'
```

The above means the same thing, but does not wrap the `created_at` column in a function.

Here is what your final query might look like:

```
SELECT
    e.data
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN device d
    ON d.id = e.device_id     -- d.id already has an index
WHERE
    d.type = 'mdc' AND        -- index (type, zone_id)
    d.zone_id = 'e451b2a1-5f6c-4a75-8038-30854926a9c0' AND   -- same index as above
    e.created_at >= '2018-03-01' AND e.created_at < '2018-03-02'
```

Comment: Why leave the `LEFT` keyword in the query? The equality predicate on a column from `d` in the WHERE clause means no NULL values will be returned. The result is equivalent to an INNER join.

Comment: @tim-biegeleisen Thanks a lot! The query has improved a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the query,  the predicates in the WHERE clause negate the outerness of the LEFT JOIN.  That is, the `LEFT` keyword is superfluous.

Wrapping a column in a function disables MySQL ability to do a range scan operation.  The condition

```
 DATE(e.created_date) = '2018-03-01'
```

Is causing MySQL to evaluate the expression on the left side for every row in the table, (or at least, every row that isn't already eliminated by some other predicate) and then compare the result to the literal on the right side.

To enable effective use of an index, this would be better written to reference bare columns

```
     e.created_date >= '2018-03-01'
 AND e.created_date <  '2018-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

With that, MySQL could make use of an range scan on a suitable index.

---

Next part would be having a suitable index available.  Given the conditions in this query... equality on `device_id` and range on `created_date`, our first stab at a suitable index would be

```
... ON `event` (`device_id`, `created_date`)
```

With that index created, we can drop the redundant index on just device_id... the new index with a leading column of device_id is sufficient to support the foreign key constraint.

Unless there is a specific reason for the redundant `id_UNIQUE` index [ `on event (id)` ], I would remove it.

It's not needed to enforce uniqueness, the PRIMARY KEY constraint already does that. Granted, it is possible this was created for an edge case that this is of benefit (where it's a covering index for a particular query. Absent that, it's not required, and a drag on DML performance.

```
DROP INDEX id_UNIQUE ON event ;
```

---

For this query, a beneficial index on the `device` table would be

```
`ON device (zone_id, device)`
```

We would expect MySQL to show "Using index" in the EXPLAIN output in the `Extra` column.

With suitable indexes available, I would write the query a little more clearly, eliminating the superfluous `LEFT` keyword.

```
SELECT e.data 
  FROM event e

  JOIN device d
    ON d.id = e.device_id 
   AND d.type = 'mdc'
   AND d.zone_id = 'e451b2a1-5f6c-4a75-8038-30854926a9c0'

 WHERE e.created_at >= '2018-03-01'
   AND e.created_at <  '2018-03-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Why remove `LEFT JOIN` from the query?  A later refactor could render your suggestion not workable.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  The `LEFT` keyword is spurious... the query is doing an INNER join. I specify an outer join when the query is actually doing an outer join, not when its doing an inner join. Specifying an outer join when an outer join isn't being performed doesn't make sense to me. Plus, based on past experience, I'm not going to depend on the SQL optimizer to recognize that its an INNER JOIN and possibly constrain itself to a less efficient plan to support an unneeded outer join. (I know the optimizer is a lot better now than it used to be in 5.1 and earlier., But still..)

Comment: You're right, good catch.  I guess the major difference would then be that forcing a left join would force a scan of one table over the other, when in fact scanning the other side might be faster.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: exactly.  but in 5.6 and later, it may not be a problem for the optimizer... its probably going to see it as an INNER join, but why risk it.  The other big issue is the future reader, avoiding unnecessary obsfucation.

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks a lot! The query has improved a lot.